# ASP.NET MVC How to upload file to dropbox and return file url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, file-upload, dropbox

I making MVC website. I would like to use dropbox for storing my files.
I find some code hove to upload files but I have no idea how to return back file url.
How to upload file to dropbox and return uploaded file url to save in db?

My code:

```
 async Task Upload(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file, string content)
{
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
    {
        var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(
            folder + "/" + file,
            WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
            body: mem);
        Console.WriteLine("Saved {0}/{1} rev {2}", folder, file, updated.Rev);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to upload file to dropbox and return uploaded file url to save in
> db?

Well, within [upload file](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial) you would see [Dropbox.Api.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsArg](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/blob/a48875be2a297d893b128ff0e10f9f6a2f127b76/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/SimpleTest/Program.cs#L447) method which has the response type of [SharedLinkMetadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload) class just like as following:

[image]

As you can see SharedLinkMetadata class has the property name URL which is :

```
public string Url { get; protected set; }
```

Above property would provide you filesharing URL metadata. Thus, you can update your Upload method as following:

```
public static async Task<string> UploadFile(string folder, string fileName, string fileUri)
        {
            var dropBoxClient = new DropboxClient("Token","AppKey");
            using (var ms = new FileStream(fileUri, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                FileMetadata updated = await dropBoxClient.Files.UploadAsync(
                folder + "/" + fileName,
                WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
                body: ms);

                var shareLinkInfo = new Dropbox.Api.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsArg(folder + "/" + fileName);
                var reponseShare = await dropBoxClient.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(shareLinkInfo);
                return reponseShare.Url;
            }
        }
```

**Note:** If you still need further information on this, please [have a look on dropbox official document here.](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload)

Comment: Your code is good for c# application but not exactly for mvc. I redact the way I get file a little bit and now it works! Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your response and gald to assist you on this.

Answer (score 0):

Using [the Dropbox .NET SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet), to create a shared link for a file, you can use [the `CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/gh-pages/obj/api/Dropbox.Api.Sharing.Routes.SharingUserRoutes.html#Dropbox_Api_Sharing_Routes_SharingUserRoutes_CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync_System_String_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_SharedLinkSettings_).

```
SharedLinkMetadata sharedLinkMetadata;
try
{
    sharedLinkMetadata = await this.client.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(path:path);
}
catch (ApiException<CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsError> err)
{
    if (err.ErrorResponse.IsSharedLinkAlreadyExists)
    {
        var sharedLinksMetadata = await this.client.Sharing.ListSharedLinksAsync(path:path, directOnly:true);
        sharedLinkMetadata = sharedLinksMetadata.Links.First();
    }
    else
    {
        throw err;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(sharedLinkMetadata.Url);
```

Or, to create a temporary direct link, you can use [the `GetTemporaryLinkAsync` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/gh-pages/obj/api/Dropbox.Api.Files.Routes.FilesUserRoutes.html#Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_GetTemporaryLinkAsync_System_String_).

Comment: Do you have any examples how to use the CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync method after uploading file method, or should I use it first?

Comment: @Ann I've added an example to my answer. That would need to be done after the upload.